# Why is there no water pressure after turning main off then back on?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, valve

Came home after work to a water leak, a coupling had corroded and come apart on the hot water line.  Turned water main off and repaired the leak but when I turned the water back on I had no hot or cold water pressure anywhere.

Replaced the main gate valve, for a few minutes I could hear air in the lines and get a tiny trickle from each faucet but after about 20 minutes I'm back to no water pressure at all.  Weird part is the toilet tank still fills up, just takes a few hours to do so.  At this point I'm willing to try anything, any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you have any filters on the main line? I've had a filter before the heater clog after shutting down the water and turning them back on.

Comment: When you say you replaced the main gate I assume you mean the first shut off gate in your home or first after the meter? To replace that gate valve you had to turn something off upstream. I'd try to disconnect the downflow side of the gate valve you replaced to test the valve. Use a bucket to catch the water. At least then you can narrow which side the problem is on. By any chance did you use any bread or "plumber's bread" when fixing the leak? Might have to clean out all your aerators if you didn't remove them before turning the water back on.

Comment: Possible duplicates [No water after reopening main water valve](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/7027/2196) and [Low water pressure after turning main water back on](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/30008/2196)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I lived in a trailer park.  Had to have water for whole park turned off to replace my main.  Did not use any bread, just used a compression fitting.  After my first post I went out and turned the water off and on again, now I get full pressure for a couple seconds and then it slows to a dribble.  This is for all faucets

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting your plumbing after your gate valve to see if you get full flow out of the valve? Is there anything between the gate valve and your faucets like a ploybutyle or pex manifold or a water softener or water filter or a hammer arrestor?